# Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger for Visual code not finding URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js

I just downloaded the VS code extension Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger. I followed the instructions but I do not get it to work. there is always an error message popping up:
[image]

When I look into my lauchn.json file I see this URL listed:

```
{
    "type": "office-addin",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Office Add-ins",
    "port": 9222,
    "trace": "verbose",
    "url":  "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=HOST$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0#",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "timeout": 5000
    }
```

I have no idea what the additional "]" in the URL means. I also tried to send a mail to the email address Microsoft provides with the addin (opencode@microsoft.com), but like usually, to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the `launch.js` file you just need to replace `HOST` with `Excel` as stated in the message box. For example, it should look like this:

```
{
    "type": "office-addin",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Office Add-ins",
    "port": 9222,
    "trace": "verbose",
    "url":  "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "timeout": 5000
    }
```

Comment: My Bad! I already changed it and changed it back and forth because I could not get the extension to work. So I changed the host to Excel and indeed the message is gone but the debug does not work! I have a problem with my page staying blank and breakpoints in the app.tsx file are not hit! 

Comment: Make sure the `url` string corresponds to the one shown on the screenshot.